# Create multiple objects in one view in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, view

I would like to create multiple objects from one view (e.g. 5 Items in one View). My View looks like:

```
@model IEnumerable<WerehouseProject.Models.ItemRentList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Dodaj</h2>

@{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialError");}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].ItemID, "Przedmiot", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].ItemID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Ilosc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Ilosc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model[i].Ilosc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ItemRentID)
    }



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    <button type="button" name="ID" value="@ViewBag.ItemRentID" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Details", "ItemRents", new { ID = @ViewBag.ItemRentID })'">Wróć</button>
</div>
```

Create GET method:

```
public ActionResult Create(int ID, int quantity)
        {
            var model = new List<ItemRentList>();
            for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
            {
                model.Add(new ItemRentList { ItemRentID = ID } );
            }
            ViewBag.ItemRentID = ID;
            ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemID", "Nazwa");
            return View(model);
        }
```

And my POST Create method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IRListID,Ilosc,ItemRentID,ItemID")] IEnumerable<ItemRentList> itemRentList)
    { 
       ... 
    }
```

My *itemRentList.ItemID* is always 0, can someone tell me how should I code View or Controller to get list of ItemRentList in POST Method?

This is my Model of ItemRentList

```
public class ItemRentList
    {
        [Key]
        public int IRListID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ilość")]
        public double Ilosc { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nazwa przedmiotu")]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

        public int ItemRentID { get; set; }
        public virtual ItemShopping ItemRent { get; set; }
    }
```

If I edit View and Controller to create only one and always one ItemRentList (not one object in list, just simple ItemRentList) then the value of ItemID is correctly bind to object, the problem is when I want to create a list of ItemRentList, then ItemID is always 0, no mater what I choose from DropDownList.

Comment: You have multiple issues. Your dropdownlist is creating multiple elements with `name="ItemID"` which wont bind to anything - it needs to be `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].ItemID, Model.YourSelectList)`. You need to remove the `[Bind]` attribute. And do not use data models in view - use a [view model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) and that modl will contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for the dropdownlist options

Comment: You POST method also needs to be `List<ItemRentList> itemRentList` so you can return the view if `ModelState` is invalid. And I assume `@model IEnumerable<ItemRentList>` is a typo and its really `@model List<ItemRentList>` other wise you view would be throwing exceptions.